# error CS1501: No overload for method 'SolvePressure' takes 12 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I have a C# class creating an instance of a C++/CLI class from a separate project (Visual Studio Express 2013). That is all fine and has been going well now for awhile. However, I just added a new method 'SolvePressure' and am getting the error
"error CS1501: No overload for method 'SolvePressure' takes 12 arguments"
when I try to build the C# project.

The C++ project builds fine, just not the C# project that references it.
The parameter number and types match up and I have verified that the method is declared publicly. Intellisense picks up the method with no problem and gives me no warnings.
I have tried rebuilding. I have tried cleaning. I'm not sure what else could be wrong. Any ideas?

For reference here is the method declaration:

```
array<double, 2>^ SolvePressure(
    double mu, double omega, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ ax, cli::array<double, 2>^ ay, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ bx, cli::array<double, 2>^ by, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ cx, cli::array<double, 2>^ cy, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ bd,
    BC2D bc0, BC2D bc1, 
    cli::array<CH2D^>^ chs);
```

And the method usage:

```
var pres = linker.SolvePressure(
    this.Mu, this.Omega, 
    ax, ay, 
    bx, by, 
    cx, cy, 
    null,
    new EigenSolver.BC2D(), new EigenSolver.BC2D(),
    new EigenSolver.CH2D[0]);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake...I forgot to mark the BC2D arguments as handles.

Fix:

```
array<double, 2>^ SolvePressure(
    double mu, double omega, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ ax, cli::array<double, 2>^ ay, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ bx, cli::array<double, 2>^ by, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ cx, cli::array<double, 2>^ cy, 
    cli::array<double, 2>^ bd,
    BC2D^ bc0, BC2D^ bc1, 
    cli::array<CH2D^>^ chs);
```

I do wish Visual Studio would throw a more informative error though...